# How to assign base address for a function pointer returning enum?

Tags: c, pointers, enums

I have a function pointer  which returns an enum
My enum is

```
typedef enum {    
    FIRST,    
    SECOND,  
    THIRD  
} STATUS;
```

In  the code some one has tried to assign a base address as

```
STATUS (*start_port)(void *,void *)= 0x80000001;
```

But it is throwing the warnings

> "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

and also

> "ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]"

I put the declaration separate

```
STATUS (*start_port)(void *,void *);
```

Then tried to assign the address to the function pointer in the following way

```
start_port = (unsigned int *)0x80000001;
```

it corrected the mixed declaration warning but a new error came up

> "assignment from incompatible pointer type"

I would  like to know how to properly type caste a function pointer to a fixed (constant) base address when the return value is an enum.

Comment: So the code for the function you want to call is actually at address `0x80000001`?

Comment: The variable `start_port` is a pointer to a function. You must cast the value to the correct type.

Comment: Re. the c90 warning: use standard C, which is C11, or at least modern C99. Don't use mideval C90 unless you **really** have to maintain some old code.

Comment: @Olaf, and also it means that whatever compiler was used has c90 as the default standard for compilation. So perhaps it's also an old compiler.

Comment: @Olaf Some smaller embedded platforms (which i guess the OP is using, considering the initialization) don't have up-to-date compilers.

Comment: @iharob: gcc before version 5 had gnu90 as standard. But that does not mean it did not support C11. Even very old versions supported c99. Also some embedded compiler default to C90, but do support c99. I don't share your pessimistic assumption. But maybe I should have added to use a modern compiler.

Comment: My code base contains legacy code so I have no choice regarding the compiler .

Comment: @achoora: regarding the compiler or the C version? Anyway, with such ballast, you have to live with this. Just follow the error message. But you cannot compliantly convert an integer or an object pointer to a function pointer. That is true for all versions.

Comment: That looks like some ARM thump code. If that is an entry point to your code, your startup code should already provide a symbol for that with correct address. Manually using a thumb address might cause problems. Better declare the function normally and export the symbol from the startup code or (if it is not) define the address in the linker control file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: For ARM (which the address smells like) typical compilers do support c99, see above. But OP already clarified this is legacy code.

Comment: This truly shows me how experience hands analyzes and solves the issues. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are declaring `start_port` of type function pointer and then try to assign a `unsigned int *` pointer to it, try

   ```
   STATUS (*start_port)(void *,void *) = (STATUS (*)(void *,void *)) 0x80000001;
   ```

   but this is terrible style and you should not do it.
2. It's a warning telling you not to declare variables inside the code, it's something that is no longer a problem with modern versions of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard but IMHO is still a good practice. Delcaring variables within the code makes it harder to follow the algorithm and the logic. Whereas declaring them only at the beginning of a block makes it easier to read the code as a whole. You know where the declarations are and you don't need to skip over parts of the code that are just "declarations".
3. The same problem as (1), so the right way to cast is

   ```
   start_port = (STATUS (*)(void *,void *)) 0x80000001;
   ```

Comment: Variable declarations should be as close to the usage as possible (for example just before a loop wherein it's used). A lengthy function can be a mess to read when you have to jump up and down all the time just to check a variable type or where it came from

Comment: A lengthy function is already a mess. If you have a lengthy function you have more things to worry about other than where you place the declarations. A function's body should fit at least in your editor's buffer, if it's longer the only reasonable explanation is a very long `switch` statement. Otherwise it's rather very easy to have bugs no matter where you declare variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer That really made my day

Answer (score 2):

As have been stated in other answers, you have to use explicit cast to convert integer into function pointer:

```
STATUS (*start_port)(void *,void *)= (STATUS(*)(void *,void *))0x80000001;
```

But function pointers are hard to read. Use `typedef` to make them more clean:

```
typedef STATUS FuncType(void*, void*);
  ...
FuncType * start_port = (FuncType *)0x80000001;
```

Comment: that is just a personal opinion. There is little use in a `typedef` if there is only one function of that type. Just consider this is a jump-table.

Comment: @Olaf `typedef` even for single usage makes code more clear. It's immediately known what's the intended usage of the pointer.

Comment: Nonsense. You still have to check two places. `typedef`s make sense if you intend to change the interface of more than one function. But here it is not likely, and even if there are more than one functions (jump-table), it is more likely one does not want to change the inteface of all functions, but a single one. So you need one `typedef` per pointer anyway. **See, how opiniated your answer is?**

Comment: @Olaf C function pointer syntax is not the prettiest in the world. Typedef makes it a lot easier to understand compared to parenthesis mess above, especially for beginners. And anyway, typedef is just a bonus: Core of the answer is that you need a cast. You are making this bigger issue than it is.

Comment: The correct way would be not to use a function pointer at all, but define a symbol in the liker or export from the code of the function. Anyway, I leave iot to the votes.

Comment: The method recommended in this answer is pretty much the de facto standard way of using function pointers. Like it or not, this is how most libraries using function pointers are designed. The only thing that's style here is if you typedef a function type, as in this example, or if you typedef a function pointer type. Personally I prefer the former since that makes typedef:ed function pointers look and behave just as normal pointers do.